# OS X: dylib file not found in /usr/lib/

Tags: java, macos, jar, dylib

I am working on a Java project; to execute a jar I required a `dylib` file, which is not present into Default OS X directory structure. If I put it manually then the program working effectively but I want it on run time, so how can I put **dylib** file into OS X directory structure?

```
.app
--contents/
----info.plist
----MacOS  <--- into this we put our jar,dylib and launcher
```

Comment: What are you using to package your JARs into an OS X .app bundle?

Comment: Thanks for  view , I use "JAR bundler" use for this purpose